# classic asp calling an api using addheader for authorization

Tags: asp-classic

I have a page that calls an api that in test mode has not required any authorization.
We are now moving to a live environment where a username and password will be required.

The api provider has sent the following message:

> To access these services please send the requests by adding following HTTP header.
>   Authorization: Basic Base64Encode(“username: password”)

I'm not sure of the correct syntax and wondered if someone could help me out.

The original call (and working perfectly) is:

```
Dim xmlobj, username, password
username="myusername"
password="mypassword"
Set xmlobj = server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
xmlobj.async = false
xmlobj.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
xmlObj.AddHeader "Authorization", "Basic", Base64Encode(username & ":" & password)
xmlobj.load(sUrl)
```

The above code throws an error

```
/api-test.asp |20|800a000d|Type_mismatch:_'Base64Encode'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Base64Encode()` is a suggested function (not built in but there are many examples online) to base64 encode the string `"username:password"` which is passed in the `Authorization` header. Once you have the function the `AddHeader` should look like `xmlObj.AddHeader "Authorization", "Basic", Base64Encode(username & ":" & password)` (assuming `username` and `password` are variables that have been set earlier. At the moment your just passing a string of `"Base64Encode('username','password')"` which the server will reject.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Changed the code to:  xmlObj.AddHeader "Authorization", "Basic", Base64Encode(username & ":" & password) as suggested (variables are set). I'm now getting the error - /api-test.asp |20|800a000d|Type_mismatch:_'Base64Encode' - any suggestions?

Comment: It's like I said the function `Base64Encode()` is not known Classic ASP, but there are plenty of examples of that function on the web. That error is telling you it doesn't understand what `Base64Encode()` is, to correct this copy the function definition from somewhere on the web into your ASP code.

Comment: Maybe this will help [Base64 encode VBS function (vb encoder algorithm), source code](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_base64encode/). My guess is this is what the API example was taken from.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in getting back to you - still trying to get my head around what you have posted. If I may try stating this in laymans terms. I need to Base64Encode the username and password in a function before passing them to the api in the xmlObj.AddHeader. I assume I can Base64Encode the user / pass using an online function and then hard code them in the call??

Comment: You could but most implementations pass different credentials so a dynamic encode is needed which is what that function does. Just test `Response.Write Base64Encode(username & ":" & password)` and see what you get. You don't need to understand `Base64Encode()` it just takes a string and returns a Base64 encoded version of that string. Just needs to function definition because it's not built into Classic ASP.

Comment: OK, so that returns: RlNEV1M6TUJSZ29sZDAx

Comment: Now I get this error: /api-test.asp |65|800a01b6|Object_doesn't_support_this_property_or_method:_'AddHeader'

Comment: I've just realised your using the `MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0` which I don't think it supports an `AddHeader` method. You want to use the `MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0` object and use `setRequestHeader()` method to accomplish the what you are trying to do above.

Comment: Have adjusted the method in my answer to reflect my comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I've mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28188457/classic-asp-calling-an-api-using-addheader-for-authorization?noredirect=1#comment44749761_28188457), the syntax for the `Authorization` header is incorrect.

The API example doesn't expect `"Base64Encode('username','password')"` this is an example supplied by the API to show you how to take the string `"username:password"` and Base64 encode it which is what the `Authorization` header is expecting.

But you still need to have the `Base64Encode()` function definition for the code to work.

> `Base64Encode()` and `MyASC()` functions are taken from [Base64 encode VBS function (vb encoder algorithm), source code](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_base64encode/)

Something like this should work;

```vb
<%
Function Base64Encode(inData)
  'rfc1521
  '2001 Antonin Foller, Motobit Software, http://Motobit.cz
  Const Base64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
  Dim cOut, sOut, I

  'For each group of 3 bytes
  For I = 1 To Len(inData) Step 3
    Dim nGroup, pOut, sGroup

    'Create one long from this 3 bytes.
    nGroup = &H10000 * Asc(Mid(inData, I, 1)) + _
      &H100 * MyASC(Mid(inData, I + 1, 1)) + MyASC(Mid(inData, I + 2, 1))

    'Oct splits the long To 8 groups with 3 bits
    nGroup = Oct(nGroup)

    'Add leading zeros
    nGroup = String(8 - Len(nGroup), "0") & nGroup

    'Convert To base64
    pOut = Mid(Base64, CLng("&o" & Mid(nGroup, 1, 2)) + 1, 1) + _
      Mid(Base64, CLng("&o" & Mid(nGroup, 3, 2)) + 1, 1) + _
      Mid(Base64, CLng("&o" & Mid(nGroup, 5, 2)) + 1, 1) + _
      Mid(Base64, CLng("&o" & Mid(nGroup, 7, 2)) + 1, 1)

    'Add the part To OutPut string
    sOut = sOut + pOut

    'Add a new line For Each 76 chars In dest (76*3/4 = 57)
    'If (I + 2) Mod 57 = 0 Then sOut = sOut + vbCrLf
  Next
  Select Case Len(inData) Mod 3
    Case 1: '8 bit final
      sOut = Left(sOut, Len(sOut) - 2) + "=="
    Case 2: '16 bit final
      sOut = Left(sOut, Len(sOut) - 1) + "="
  End Select
  Base64Encode = sOut
End Function

Function MyASC(OneChar)
  If OneChar = "" Then MyASC = 0 Else MyASC = Asc(OneChar)
End Function

Dim xmlobj, username, password
username="myusername"
password="mypassword"
Set xmlobj = server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
xmlobj.Open "GET", sUrl, False
xmlobj.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & Base64Encode(username & ":" & password)
xmlobj.Send

Dim xmldoc
If xmlobj.status = 200 Then
  Set xmldoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
  xmldoc.Load xmlobj.ResponseXML
Else
  Response.Write "An error occurred!"
End If
%>
```

Comment: OK couple of little errors in the code. xml.Open need to be xmlobj.Open and "Basic", Base64Encode(username & ":" & password) needs to be "Basic"&Base64Encode(username & ":" & password) (I think!!) or the error Wrong_number_of_arguments_or_invalid_property_assignment:_'setRequestHeader' is thrown. After those  changes are made I now get this error: Security_certificate_required_to_access_this_resource_is_invalid.

Comment: @user2369824 You're right sorry was just pseudo coded. Have corrected it but I think the `"Basic"&Base64Encode(username & ":" & password)` needs a space (see my edit). For example it should end up like `Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==` (example taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)).

Comment: Amended the code accordingly and to solve the security certificate issue in my previous comment I call my page over https. Now it takes around 10 seconds for the page to load - but I just get a blank page.

Comment: @user2369824 Of course you will have a blank page it loads the xml into an XMLDOM object but what does the code do next? You have to tell it to display. I thought you said this worked previously? What is it meant to do?